# Import EBCDIC file to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ebcdic

I have a file (10 gigs) in an export from a Mainframe database in EBCDIC format.   I am trying to get this into a SQL Server 2008 database to query for a client.  I am 100% clueless about conversion or import of this format.   Repeated Google searches have not yielded any usable results.   Any help would be appreciated.  I do have a schema document that came with the export.  The vendor is no help though.   At this point I am willing to just pay someone for conversion if needed.

Comment: Do you have packed decimal data (comp-3) in it or is it just an EBCDIC to ASCII conversion?

Answer (score 3):

See my answer at [Reading a Cobol generated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877379/reading-a-cobol-generated-file/4878481#4878481). It may help figure it out.

Comment: Your answer gave me a headache but thanks.   I'm glad I never had to learn that!

Answer (score 0):

Amino Software makes a component to solve this exact problem, called Lysine.

http://aminosoftware.com

Comment: Thanks I am taking a look.  Have you used it?